# I've been trying to run this PYTHON code from a roguelike tutorial but it replies with an error (SOLVED)

Tags: python, roguelike

So, my code is this bad boy here

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tcod

def main() -> None:
    screen_width = 80
    screen_height = 50

    tiileset = tcod.tileset.load_tilesheet(
        "dejavu10x10_gs_tc.png", 32, 8, tcod.tileset.CHARMAP_TCOD
    )

    with tcod.context.new_terminal(
        screen_width,
        screen_height,
        tileset=tiileset,
        title = "Yet Another Roguelike Tutorial",
        vsync=True,
    ) as context:
        root_console = tcod.Console(screen_width, screen_height, order="F")
    while True:
        root_console.print(x=1,y=1,string="@")

        context.present(root_console)

        for event in tcod.event.wait():
            if event.type == "QUIT":
                raise SystemExit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I should see an @ when I run the code with python3, but, instead, it gives me this message
"**AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute '_context_p'**"
It sort of sounds obvious what's the problem, but I can't figure out how to solve, can you folks help me?
EDIT: The problem was the indentation on some lines

```py
with tcod.context.new_terminal(
        screen_width,
        screen_height,
        tileset=tiileset,
        title = "Yet Another Roguelike Tutorial",
        vsync=True,
    ) as context:
        root_console = tcod.Console(screen_width, screen_height, order="F")
        while True:
            root_console.print(x=player_x,y=player_y,string="@") #defines the player (in this case is this @)

            context.present(root_console)

            root_console.clear() #clears path behind our player 

            for event in tcod.event.wait():
                action = event_handler.dispatch(event)

                if action is None:
                    continue
                
                if isinstance(action, MovementAction):
                    player_x += action.dx
                    player_y += action.dy

                elif isinstance(action, EscapeAction):
                    raise SystemExit()
```

It should be this way, this is why it wasn´t working, and it was a syntax error that was preventing it from running properly

Comment: I suspect that your `while True:` loop needs to be indented another level, so it's part of the `with` statement.

Comment: Yeah, it fixed, but still, it made my program run but the window always stop running and I need to force quit it :(